# post image to mongodb using express nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to post to mongodb using express nodejs and this is the code of add route:

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {

  const validating = userValidating(req.body);
  if (validating.error) {
    res.status(400).send(validating.error.details);
  } else {
    var path = "images/"+req.file.image;
    res.send(path);
    var image = req.files.image;
    fileName = uuidv1();
    const user = new User({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      image: req.file.image,
      title: req.body.title
    });

    const v = user.validateSync();

    if (v)
      res.status(400).send('somthing wrong');

    user.save()
      .then(result => {

        res.send('You have added a new user');

        image.mv(`./public/images/${fileName}.png`, function(err) {
          if (err)
            return res.status(500).send(err);
          res.send('File uploaded!');
        });
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {

        res.status(401).send(err);
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
});
```

and this is the function of validation that I used above:

```
function userValidating(user) {
  const userSchema = {
    'image': Joi.string().required(),
    'title': Joi.string().required()
  }
  return Joi.validate(user, userSchema);
}
```

when I tried in postman using form-data like this:

[image]

you can see that I get this error of image is required even if I change the image to req.body.image instead of req.file.image

also I tried to use Body raw in postman instead of form-data and write json like this:

```
{
    "image": "uuu",
    "title": "uuuu"
}
```

and it works fine

what's the problem with code?

Comment: You surely don't get the same error when you actually set `image` in the body? The code looks problematic in other places so I presume it's passing the validation in that scenario but failing elsewhere.

Comment: I get same error when I set the type of image key to text instead of file and change the code too from req.file.image to req.body.image @James

Comment: @James  but when I use Body raw in postman instead of form-data and write json and tried to post it then it works fine